# Show list-items in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm pretty new to c# and MVC

I created a FormController.cs with a method like:

```
public ActionResult Showlist()
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        list.Add(54);
        list.Add(524);
        list.Add(23);
        list.Add(43);

        return View(list);
    }
```

Then I create a view from that method. In my div-tags I put the text like:

```
<body>
    <div>
        @Model.ToString();
    </div>
</body>
```

The result is a view with the text `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] ``

My question: What's a good (or best) way to show the values that I added in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to declare the Model as a list in the cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<int>

@{
  foreach (var anInt in Model)
  {
    <text>@anInt</text>
  }
}
```

Comment: if he haven't declare the model he would get a NullReferenceException, instead of `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]`

Comment: @Selman...Understood.  I just added it for clarity.  Not everyone would know that.